# FireBase getInstance crashed with my Wrapped APK through MDX Tool

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to find the crash happening with an app I have developed.

App is getting crashed while getting the instance of Firebase, this happens only with the app downloaded from MDM App hub, works fine with emulator and device launch through direct flash or download from playstore, this exception occurs with the app downloaded from MDM App hub from the client

Client has included the senderid and API key on MDX tool before wrapping it.

Here are the logs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.name' on a null object reference
 at com.citrix.mdx.f.a.a(Unknown Source)
 at com.citrix.mdx.f.a.a(Unknown Source)
 at com.citrix.MAM.Android.ManagedApp.l.a(Unknown Source)
 at com.citrix.MAM.Android.ManagedApp.l.a(Unknown Source)
 at com.citrix.MAM.Android.ManagedApp.l.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at com.citrix.mdx.e.d.b(Unknown Source)
 at citrix.android.content.pm.PackageManager.queryIntentServices_aroundBody5$advice(Unknown Source)
 at citrix.android.content.pm.PackageManager.queryIntentServices(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.zzdf(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzem(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zza(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
 at citrix.android.content.pm.PackageManager.queryIntentServices_aroundBody5$advice(Unknown Source)
 at citrix.android.content.pm.PackageManager.queryIntentServices(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.zzdf(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzem(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zza(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Exception is thrown at this line in the code:

```
  case R.id.register_btn:
            if (validateInput()) {
                showProgress("Loading...");
                String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        //here is where am getting null pointer exception only with wrapped apk 
                     final String firebaseId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
                String myVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;

                final LoginData signUpData = new LoginData(userId_et.getText().toString().trim(), password_et.getText().toString(), "ANDROID " + myVersion, phone_et.getText().toString(), firebaseId);
                apiService.userLogin(signUpData).enqueue(new Callback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<LoginResult> call, Response<LoginResult> response) {
                        dismissProgress();
  }
```

Below is my gradle level code:

```
dependencies {

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project level Gradle file:

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Firebase Service Registration in Manifest

```
        <!-- [START firebase_service] -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <service
        android:name=".service.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.fc.debug" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- [END firebase_service] -->
    <!-- [START firebase_iid_service] -->
    <service android:name=".service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <!-- [END firebase_iid_service] -->
```

Class `MyFirebaseInstanceIDService`:

```
      public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

/**
 * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
 * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
 * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
 */
// [START refresh_token]
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
         //        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    String refreshedToken = " ";
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
    // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
    // Instance ID token to your app server.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}
// [END refresh_token]

/**
 * Persist token to third-party servers.
 * <p>
 * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
 * maintained by your application.
 *
 * @param token The new token.
 */
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
}
}
```

`MyApplication` Class:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

}
}
```

Comment: Where in your code are you using `firebaseId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();`? Can please share more code?

Comment: at the time of registration am getting the token and sending to the server to use it for notifications.

Comment: @Alex Mamo edited with the code

Comment: And you areg etting ` Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field` at which line?

Comment: at this line 
 //here is where am getting null pointer exception only with wrapped apk 
                     final String firebaseId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

Comment: This means that `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().` returns `null`. Are you correctly authenticated?

Comment: I had not done any authentication explicitly, i wanted just the token to work with Push notifications, for that i had declared the IDservice in manifest and initialized the firebase in my application class i updated that too in the question now correct me if am in a wrong way, but with the above code my app works fine, i had the problem only with wrapped APP from MDX tool

Comment: is this solved? i'm getting exactly same problem.

Comment: You cracked it i had done the same way sitting with citrix guys

Answer (score 0):

I was getting exacly same error message on my application and created a ticket on Citrix support website.

These 2 items resolved my issue.

> In order to be able to send PUSH notifications with MDX-wrapped
>   applications, please ensure
>
> 1. Firebase Cloud Messaging (Google Cloud Messaging) is enabled on the XenMobile server itself and ports are opened:
>      https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xenmobile/server/provision-devices/google-cloud-messaging.html
> 2. Check "{pkg=com.google.firebase}" is in the "Restricted Open-In Exception List" in the MDX policies for the application.

Answer (score -1):

Try to update project level grandle like:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Also grandle level:

```
dependencies {

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```